# Monotouch Threading - order/priority of requests

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I had some performance issues when using an UICollectionView where the cell was showing an Image (loaded from the HD).

I solved that issue by loading the image in the background.

Basically, in my "GetCell" method I check if the image is in my ImageCache.

- If so, set the image on my ImageView in the cell.
- If not, load the image in the background and request a reload for that specific
  item (I request a reload because I don't know if the cell is recycled
  in the meanwhile, so it's not safe to directly set the image)

Snippet of my background process:

```cs
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (delegate { 
                    ImagesCache.AddImageToCache(""+indexPath.Row,ImageForPosition(indexPath.Row));
                    InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 
                        collectionView.ReloadItems(Converter.ToIndexPathArray(indexPath));
                    });
                });
```

It works ok, but if you scroll fast, it will load all these async tasks and the problem is that it will execute the requests in order (FIFO). So when you scroll fast, images for invisible cells will be loaded before images from visible cells.

Does anyone has an idea how I could optimise this process to get a better user experience?
Because if I would extend this to include images from the internet, the problem will be worse (because of the download).

Increasing the max amount of simultaneously threads will allow the later added threads to already start immediately but it will decrease the overall performance/download speed, so that's also not a real solution.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project's solution in short: one `thread` to download images with `queue` support. Plus checking in target `UI` control, that it wasn't dequeued for reuse.

Long version:

- Implement `queue` with methods `Start`/`Stop`. When `Start` is calling, start background thread, which in busy loop (`while true { DoSomething(); }`) will try to dequeue request from queue. If not dequeued, sleep a bit. If dequeued, execute it (download image). `Stop` method should say thread to exit from loop:

```cs
public void Start()
{
    if (started) {
        return;
    }
    started = true;

    new Thread (new ThreadStart (() => {
        while (started) {
            var request = GetRequest();
            if (request != null) {
                request.State = RequestState.Executing;
                Download (request);
            } else {
                Thread.Sleep (QueueSleepTime);
            }
        }
    })).Start ();
}

public void Stop()
{
    started = false;
}
```

- Then, make a private method in `queue` to download image with such logic: check for image in file cache. If file is available, read and return it. If not, download it, save it to file, return it (call `Action<UIImage> onDownload`) or error (call `Action<Exception> onError`). Call this method in `queue`'s busy loop. Name it `Download`:

```cs
public Download(Request request)
{
    try {
        var image = GetImageFromCache(request.Url);
        if (image == null) {
            image = DownloadImageFromServer(request.Url); // Could be synchronous
        }
        request.OnDownload(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        request.OnError(e);
    }
}
```

- Then, make a public method to add request to queue. Pattern [`Command`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is useful for wrapping requests for queue: storing `Actions`, current `State`. Name it `DownloadImageAsync`:

```cs
public DownloadImageAsync(string imageUrl, Action<UIImage> onDownload, Action<Exception> onError)
{
    var request = MakeRequestCommand(imageUrl, onDownload, onError);
    queue.Enqueue(request);
}
```

- When `UITableViewCell` is preparing to show and request to download image:

```cs
// Custom UITableViewCell method, which is called in `UITableViewSource`'s `GetCell`
public void PrepareToShow()
{
    var imageURLClosure = imageURL;
    queue.DownloadImageAsync(imageURL, (UIImage image) => {
        if (imageURLClosure == imageURL) {
            // Cell was not dequeued. URL from request and from cell are equals.
            imageView.Image = image;
        } else {
            // Do nothing. Cell was dequeued, imageURL was changed.
        }
    }, (Exception e) => {
        // Set default image. Log.
    });
}
```

Checking for (imageURLClosure == imageURL) is imprtant to avoid showing multiple images in one `UIImageView` when scrolls fast. One cell could initialize multiple request, but only last one result should be used.

Futher improvements:

- LIFO execution. If no requests are already run, add new one to begin.
- Using `Action<byte[]> onDownload` instead of `Action<UIImage> onDownload` for cross-platform code compatibility;
- Availability to cancel `download image` request when cell become insivisble (`WillMoveToSuperview`). Well, it's not very necessary. After first downloading, image will be in cache, so any further requests for image will be done fast. Thanks to cache;
- In-memory cache. Thus, in worst case, chain will be:

`Find image in in-memory cache` -> `Find image in file cache` -> `Downloading from server`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had some other urgent priorities. Interesting concept (queue or stack can be used with it)! Thanks for the help. I have some question about your "var imageURLClosure = imageURL;". I understand your goal of this line. If the Cell is recycled, the 'imageUrl' will contain the old value and "imageURLClosure == imageURL" will return false I assume. However, that means that 'imageURLClosure' doesn't contain that same old value anymore after the download. How does that come? (with other words, what happens with 'imageURLClosure' exactly when the cell is recycled)

Comment: `imageURLClosure` is primitive string. It will be copied into `DownloadImageAsync`'s `onDownload` action. It's value in action will be unchanged (copy, not a reference of `imageURL`). On the contrary, `imageURL` will be changed after dequeue reusable cell.